# Which ReThinkDB .NET driver should I use? What are the functional differences between them?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, .net-core, rethinkdb

I'm interested in RethinkDB's real-time data pushing capabilities, and want to integrate it into my .net core web API. Only problem is, I see that the company behind ReThinkDB has shut down, and its fate is in the hands of the community.

There are currently 2 community made .NET drivers for RethinkDB :

https://github.com/bchavez/RethinkDb.Driver

and

https://github.com/mfenniak/rethinkdb-net

I can't find any documentation on either of these drivers, and am at a loss as to which one I should use. I don't want to start with one driver, only to find out months later that the project has been abandoned. Any guidance here would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you posted this in the .NET Core tag, I'd strongly recommend [RethinkDb.Driver](https://github.com/bchavez/RethinkDb.Driver) as it's the only one (at the time of writing) that supports .NET Standard.

Comment: How to use this driver actually? No guide at all. I mean how rethink db will send the data to application/trigger action ?